# Editing content of textbox from a class

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.8

I'm fairly new to programming with C#, I'm trying to change the value of a textbox in my main Form called "ClientWindow", the textbox is called ClientConsoleTextBox. I tried doing this:

```
public static string ClientConsoleText;
```

and then when the ClientConsoleTextBox initializes I set this in the event properties like so:

```
private void ClientConsoleTextBox_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    ClientConsoleTextBox.Text = ClientConsoleText;
 }
```

I can change the string "ClientConsoleText" but the "ClientConsoleTextBox.Text" string never get's updated with any text I may add to the string ex.Button that does:

```
private void TestButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   ClientConsoleText += "TestString";
}
```

The goal is to update the text from other classes.

I have tried to search for answers but none of them break down the issue in a clear way.
Some say I have to create a new instance of my main window..?

Again. Sorry if the solution is obvious and I cannot seem to understand it, I started C# and wpf a week ago :)

Thanks in advance and good day!

Comment: Have you tried adding this `ClientConsoleTextBox.Text = ClientConsoleText;` to the end of your `TestButton_Click` method?

Comment: It works when I do it on the same class. But not when I try to change the textbox from another class, which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: To change the textbox content from another class, you can try to create a public method on the current class and call it from the other one.

Comment: This would require me to also make it static therefore rendering the use of the text inside the textbox impossible... I just tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use TextBox.Text property to update UI,

```
ClientConsoleText += "TestString";
ClientConsoleTextBox.Text = ClientConsoleText;
```

or implement the interface INotifyPropertyChanged,use binding to update UI

```
   public class SimpleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
    private string myText;

    public string MyText
    {
        get
        {
            return myText;
        }
        set
        {
            myText = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyText")));
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  }
```

MainWindow.Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<StackPanel>
    <!--Binding to SimpleViewModel.MyText-->
    <TextBox  Text="{Binding MyText}"/>
    <Button Content="Update" Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

MainWindow.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    SimpleViewModel viewmodel = new SimpleViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = viewmodel();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //get  textbox value 
        var text = viewmodel.MyText;

        //set textbox value
        viewmodel.MyText = "HelloWorld";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for providing to my post! Is this less resource-intensive and a better design choice than the timer implementation I used?

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are describing is databinding and you would have to have a class, with  ClientConsoleText as a property and then Set up a Datasource pointing at the class.

A simpler way, but I do not know if it will meet your goals would be to setup a property called ClientConsoleText at the form level that reads and writes to the textbox.

Example code:

```
 public string ClientConsoleText
    {
        get { return ClientConsoleTextBox.Text; }
        set { ClientConsoleTextBox.Text = value; }
    }
```

Now if you assign ClientConsoleText = "hello" then "hello" will be in the textbox.
You can also get the value of the textbox by referencing ClientConsoleText, Example:

```
string s = ClientConsoleText;
```

Hope this helps. If not maybe you could explain what the goal is.

Comment: the string HAS to be static... I'm basically looking for a way to make the data inside a textbox static to be used with other forms and classes. I'm really thankful for the time you've put in helping me but this solution would be 100% what I were looking for if I could set the string as:

`public string ClientConsoleText
    {
        get { return ClientConsoleTextBox.Text; }
        set { ClientConsoleTextBox.Text = value; }
    }`

Comment: If I understand you correctly all forms would show the same value in the textbox, a change made to the text should then refresh for any form using this textbox. So they would all show the same text. Is that what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a timer like so:

```
        private void ClientConsoleTextBox_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();

        }
```

And then on every 100 milliseconds it would:

```
        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClientConsoleTextBox.Text = ClientConsoleText;
        }
```

Essentially, updating the textbox on it's own!
Maybe it's a poor design choice but it's what's worked for me, hope this helps someone in the future :) Good night.